# ConTeXt: how to use multiple units simultaneously

Tags: context, units

The goal is to print something like `1 h 20 m 56 s` using `units` module and more specifically the `\unit{ }` command.

I know it is possible to use unit macros like this:

```tex
1 \Hour 20 \Minute 50 \Second
```

but I find it more readable to have

```tex
\unit{1 hour 20 minute 56 second}
```

however the latter does not work and produce

[image]

Is it possible to make this?

Of course, this is not only about hours, and I'd like it to works with other units, for example `2 m 47 cm`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discussed this with Hans. You won't be able to type

```
\unit{1 hour 20 minute 56 second}
```

simply because of compatibility issues. The digit 2 at that place is automatically (as you noticed) converted to a superscript 2.

After the next upload you can do (I put the units in math, then the spaces are driven by the classes)

```
\startTEXpage[offset=1dk]
\im {1 \unit{hour} 20 \unit{minute} 56 \unit{second} }\par
\im{ 2 \unit{m} 47 \unit{cm} }\par
\im{ \unit{2 m} \unit{47 cm} }
\stopTEXpage
```

The result is

[image: Some units]

If you need an urgent temporary fix, you can (at least for the first variants with the numbers outside the `\unit`) try

```
\unprotect
\inherited\setmathspacing \mathdimensioncode \mathdigitcode \allmathstyles \thickmuskip

\def\phys_units_start
   {\ifmmode
      \dostarttagged\t!maction\t!unit
      \mathatom
         \s!leftclass  \mathdimensioncode
         \s!rightclass \mathdimensioncode % \mathordinarycode
      \bgroup
    \else
      \dostarttagged\t!unit\empty
    \fi
    \let\phys_units_finish\phys_units_stop
    \let\phys_units_start\relax}
\protect
```